# Do other packages see changes made to objects inside factory methods in python?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to integrate SQLAlchemy into my application. I currently use application factories. my `app/__init__.py` looks like below

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)

    from app.views.admin import admin

    app.register_blueprint(frontend)

    return app
```

Now I want to use sqlalchemy but the sqlalchemy object needs an instance of my app to be properly constructed. This documentation http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/, recommends that I create this object in a separate file like say `model.py`

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Then inside my factory method create_app in `__init__.py`, I add this

```
from app.model import db
db.init_app(app)
```

Now my question is, if I import `db` in other files, will I be importing a db that has been initialized with an instance of my app or just what is declared in the `model.py` file.

Comment: Yes, in other modules, `from app.model import db` will return the same object that was mutated in `db.init_app()`. The only way you'd run into trouble with this is if you had multiple `db = SQLAlchemy()` statements in different modules.

Comment: Thanks @SuperShoot

Comment: An easy test of this is to use the builtin [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function. The same instance will have the same id, so put `print(id(db))` in your `create_app()` method and in the other module where you are using `db` and they'll be the same number. If they aren't then you are using different instances.